# How do I use a case and an if statement inside an update...set in mysql?

Tags: mysql

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
UPDATE
    my_table
SET
    column_a = (
        SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN column_a is null THEN 20
            WHEN column_a < 10 THEN column_a
            WHEN column_a = 10 THEN 20
            ELSE MIN((column_a, 20))
        END
        INTO @var_a
        /* I want to do an if...else now */
        IF(var_a > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), null, var_a)
    )
WHERE
    column_b = 'something'
```

How would I do something like this? Thanks!

Comment: By `MIN(column_a, 20)`, do you mean to get whichever is least?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes

Comment: And what expression is `some_expression_with_var_a`? All of this should be expressible inside the `CASE` alone.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It's another comparison using var_a. I do this: `var_a > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: Does the table also have a unique id column of some sort? Stuffing this into a join against itself may work if there's a good column to join on.

Comment: If you find yourself playing *20 questions* with someone about your question, it means that you've done a poor job of explaining the problem you're having and that you should [edit] your question to make the problem more clear.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski There's an index on the primary key which is just a id column and an index on the column_b I have in the where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a nested `case` to do this:

```
UPDATE
    my_table
SET
    column_a = (
        case
            when (@var_a := (
                case 
                    when column_a is null then 20
                    when column_a < 10 then column_a
                    when column_a = 10 then 20
                    else least(column_a, 20)
                end)) <= unix_timestamp() then @var_a
            else null
        end)
WHERE
    column_b = 'something';
```

Notice that `min()` is an *aggregate function* and you can't use it to get the minimum of the inputs: You need to use [`least()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least).

Hope this helps

Comment: I'll try this out, thanks! Yea I know about MIN, I forgot to include a set of parenthesis. The values I put in the question are examples. They're actually timestamps and will be relatively close to UNIX_TIMESTAMP().